# How can I display last message time of firebase at the top in recyclerView in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

As now i am working on a chat application, here i have a problem that how can i display my **last recent chat on the top of the recyclerview in ChatlistFragment**,
for example if i had recently sent my last message to any user they have to displayed at the top of my recyclerview, here is my code

```
package com.micoder.whatsappclone;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton;
import com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {

    private View PrivateChatsView;
    private RecyclerView chatsList;
    private DatabaseReference ChatsRef, UsersRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserID;

    FloatingActionMenu fabMenu;
    FloatingActionButton fabSettings, fabShare, fabContactDev;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        PrivateChatsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        ChatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages").child(currentUserID);
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        chatsList = (RecyclerView) PrivateChatsView.findViewById(R.id.chats_list);
        chatsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        fabOptions();

        return PrivateChatsView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                        .setQuery(ChatsRef, Contacts.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ChatsViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ChatsViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Contacts model) {
                        final String usersIDs = getRef(position).getKey();
                        final String[] retImage = {"default_image"};

                        UsersRef.child(usersIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                                if (dataSnapshot.child("userState").hasChild("state")) {

                                    String state = dataSnapshot.child("userState").child("state").getValue().toString();

                                    if (state.equals("online")) {
                                        holder.onlineIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    }
                                    else if (state.equals("offline")) {
                                        holder.onlineIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    holder.onlineIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }



                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")) {
                                        retImage[0] = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                                        Picasso.get().load(retImage[0]).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profileImage);
                                    }


                                    final String retName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();


                                    holder.userName.setText(retName);


                                    if (dataSnapshot.child("userState").hasChild("state")) {

                                        String state = dataSnapshot.child("userState").child("state").getValue().toString();
                                        String date = dataSnapshot.child("userState").child("date").getValue().toString();
                                        String time = dataSnapshot.child("userState").child("time").getValue().toString();

                                        if (state.equals("online")) {
                                            holder.userStatus.setText("online");
                                        }
                                        else if (state.equals("offline")) {
                                            holder.userStatus.setText("Last Seen: " + date + " " + time);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        holder.userStatus.setText("offline");
                                    }


                                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", usersIDs);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_name", retName);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("visit_image", retImage[0]);
                                            startActivity(chatIntent);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ChatsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_chats_layout, viewGroup, false);
                        return new ChatsViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };

        chatsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }


    public static class ChatsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CircleImageView profileImage;
        TextView userName, userStatus;
        ImageView onlineIcon;

        public ChatsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
            onlineIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_online_status);
        }
    }

    public void fabOptions() {

        //FAB
        fabMenu=PrivateChatsView.findViewById(R.id.fabMenu);
        fabSettings=PrivateChatsView.findViewById(R.id.fabSettings);
        fabContactDev=PrivateChatsView.findViewById(R.id.fabContactDev);
        fabShare=PrivateChatsView.findViewById(R.id.fabShare);

        fabShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
                    String shareMessage= "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
                    shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=MI_CODER"+"\n\n";
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "choose one"));
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    //e.toString();
                }
                fabMenu.close(true);
            }
        });
        fabSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),SettingsActivity.class));
                fabMenu.close(true);
            }
        });
        fabContactDev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://micoder-dev.github.io/Resume-Page/"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                fabMenu.close(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

if you need to refer my complete source code you can get here => https://github.com/Micoder-dev/ChatApp-FE-UI.git

I think this will help you to make it easier to get a solution.

Comment: The topic of showing nodes from the database in descending order has been covered a few times before, so I recommend checking out: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bfirebaseui%5D%5Bandroid%5D+descending

Comment: If the links don't allow you to fix the problem, consider posting a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with details on the exact lines of code that don't do what you expect them to do (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Comment: hello sir, there is no questions helps me to fix my problem because i am not looking for a descending order from firebase i am looking for a last message time that should have to be displayed on top of the recycler view fragment

Comment: See my second comment in that case, as it's unclear at the moment what part of your code doesn't do what you expect it to do.